# How to get the id of visible divs

Tags: jquery

I have many divs, out of which some of them are visible; I want to get the ID of the visible ones:

The following code always return the first div; why is that?

```
   alert($("div.my_div:visible").attr("id"));
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/zrvRc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `:visible` doesn't work with CSS' visibility (["Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout."](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)), you can use:

```
$("div.my_div").each(function () {
    if ($(this).css('visibility') != 'hidden') console.log(this.id);
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zrvRc/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

You are using `visibility:hidden` css propery for your element, so that `:visible` selector wont consider that as `display:none`. So what you need to do in this context is you have to filter the collection by checking whether the elements in the collection is having the property `visibility:hidden` or not, then you have to group its id by using `.map()` and make that group as an array by using `.get()` and `.join()` that array as per your need with any delimiters..

Try,

```
alert($("div.my_div")
      .filter(function(){ 
            return $(this).css('visibility') === "hidden"; 
      })
      .map(function(){ 
            return this.id; 
      }).get().join(''));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zrvRc/3/)

Comment: This returns all divs(including both visible and invisible!)

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem with the OP's code is.

Comment: @user: how can it if the selector includes the `:visible` selector?

Comment: Doesn't `:visible` only check the `display` css attribute?